# Manipulating array outside of function using pointer?

Tags: c, arrays

**KEEP IN MIND I WROTE THIS CODE IN HERE TO SIMPLIFY MY QUESTION, PLEASE IGNORE MINOR MISTAKES IF THERE ARE ANY, MY PROBLEM FOCUSES ON MANIPULATING AN ARRAY OUTSIDE OF A FUNCTION BY USING IT'S POINTER.**

I create a static array like this

```
char *array[size1][size2];
```

For the purposes of my example size1 = 3 and size2 = 6.

Then I use a function to pass the pointer of the array, and allocate strings to it.

```
int counter = 0;

void somefunction(char *a, char *b, int size1){
 while(counter<size1){
   //do some stuff to a
   strcpy(b+counter, a);
   counter++;
   printf("Adding %s to pos %i RESULT: %s\n",a,counter,b+counter);
 }

}
```

This works nicely and the output is correct (when outputting array b in the function), but it does not actually effect the array[] outside of the function. If I use

```
somefunction(a,array,size1);
```

The output will be correct, but the actual array outside of the function (array[]) will output gibberish random memory.

I output it like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<size1;i++){
    printf("%s\n",array[i]);
}
```

So what am i doing wrong here? I thought the array when passed to a function decays into a pointer to the first element (and therefore that array), but that doesn't seem to be the case. What am I doing wrong? How do I manipulate the array outside of the function by passing it's pointer?

Thanks!

Comment: Your array is 2D array and are you sure you are passing and reading correct dimension? I would pass `&array[0][0]`

Comment: @Swanad.  `&array[0][0]` is a pointer to a pointer.  Passing it to a function expecting a `char *` is invalid.

Comment: Do you want to have a list of strings or 2D array of strings?

Comment: Anyway, "decaying" of an array to a pointer only works as advertized on one dimensional arrays.  If passing a n-dimensional array, the array name will "decay" into a pointer to an "n-1"-dimensional array.

Comment: Marek, I want to have a list of strings that I can count through.

@Peter Wow I did not know that! What would be the best way to achieve what I'm trying to do in this case?

Comment: It seems you are confusing a statically allocated string array - a 2D array of characters - with an array of pointers to any string - `char* []`. When you want an array of pointers to strings you would declare it as `char* array [size];` but then you must allocate memory for the strings elsewhere. So what are you actually trying to do here...?

Comment: @Aldo What do `3` and `6` represent in your mind? A list of strings only needs 1 length, so do you have 3 strings, 6 strings, or (3 * 6) = 18 strings?

Comment: The main question would be: are size1 and size2 constant expressions? If yes, this would make things much easier

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I'm certainly confused about this. What Im trying to do is I calculate the length of the string (size2). So all of the strings contained will be of length 3 in this case, "ABC" for example. Size 1 is simply the amount of strings of size 3 that I need to store and iterate through. So size1=6 size2=3 means I want to have 6 strings accesable by ordered array, all of which are 3 chars in length. Once I compute size1 and size2 (I do this before creating the array) they do indeed stay constant.

Comment: The compiler, when compiling the function needs to know the size of the second dimension, suggest: `void somefunction(char *a, char b[][size2], int size1){`  then when the code says: `strcpy(b+counter, a);` the correct increment through memory (6 bytes) times the value in `counter`.   However ever this will fail if the length of the array `a` is greater than `size2-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> What Im trying to do is I calculate the length of the string (size2). So all of the strings contained will be of length 3 in this case, "ABC" for example. Size 1 is simply the amount of strings of size 3 that I need to store and iterate through. So size1=6 size2=3 means I want to have 6 strings accesable by ordered array, all of which are 3 chars in length. Once I compute size1 and size2 (I do this before creating the array) they do indeed stay constant.

In that case, you want to declare `array` as a 2D array of `char`:

```
char array[size1][size2]; // no *
```

Note that to store a string of length `N`, you need an `N`+1-element array to account for the 0 terminator.  So if you're storing strings like `"ABC"` (`{'A','B','C',0}`), then `size2` needs to be 4, not 3.

When you pass it to `somefunction`, the type of the *expression* `array` "decays" to "pointer to `size2`-element array of `char`" (`char (*)[size2]`)<sup>1</sup>.  Based on your description, it sounds like you declare `array` as a *variable-length* array (i.e., `size1` and `size2` are not known until runtime).  If that's the case, then your function definition needs to look like

```
/**
 * size2 must be declared in the argument list before char (*b)[size2]
 * b may also be declared as char b[][size2]; it means the same thing
 */
void somefunction( char *a, size_t size2, char (*b)[size2], size_t size ) 
{
  ...
  strcpy( b[counter], a );
  ...
}
```

and should be called as

```
somefunction( a, size2, array, size1 );
```

---

1. Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.  In your case, N is `size1` and `T` is "`size2`-element array of `char`".

Comment: I didn't mention this because I thought it wouldn't be relevant, but somefunction is actually a recursive function (for calculating permutations), so preferably I don't want to pass any static arguments... I might just go the lazy way and make a global array to simplify all of this. I will be back tomorrow and retry implementing your code, I'm too tired now. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much, took me a couple of days messing with strings and array, but now I fully understand it!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need this:

```
char *array[SIZE];
```

Some function then looks like this:

```
int counter = 0;

void somefunction(char *a, char **b){
    while(counter < SIZE){
        //do some stuff to a
        *(b+counter) = calloc(sizeof(char), strlen(a)+1);
        strcpy(*(b+counter), a);
        counter++;
        printf("Adding %s to pos %i RESULT: %s\n",a,counter,b+counter);
    }
}
```